# Nginx can only load 3 pages. The other pages give a error but still 200 status

Tags: node.js, nginx, server

I got this error when i tried loading /contact page or testing if my error page is working when there is a page not found i get this error
`{"error":{"text":"Too many requests in this time frame.","nextValidRequestDate":"some time"}}` it only works on the home page, image page, reviews page. I get a 200 status on the pages with the error. This is my nginx domain config

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=15r/s;

upstream node2 {
        least_conn;
        server 127.0.0.1:3000 weight=3;
        server 127.0.0.1:3001 weight=2;
        zone node2 64k;
}

server {

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    client_body_timeout 5s;
    client_header_timeout 5s;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains;";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

    location / {

        limit_req zone=one burst=20 nodelay;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://node2/;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot






}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

all pages are loading fine but 1 not i don't know what is the problem. The error log doesnt return a rate limit error on the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if that error is coming from your node.js application